# popup show when I move to another view controller

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, popup

I'm stuck at something, here's what I did:

I have a view controller called "popup". It works like a popup, I can show it everywhere using a button.

So when I perform a segue from view controller name (a) to view controller name (b) , I want my popup shows automatically, without having to show a button. How can I do that?

Comment: add popup code in viewdidappear()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to set it's code inside

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear()
    if let popup = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "popupID") {
        self.present(popup, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    
}
```

Comment: thank you it worked !! being I beginner is such a hard thing

Comment: how can I stop it being appears , I just want the user see it for one time

Comment: try viewWillAppear or wrap code inside a bool value that you set to false inside the if statement

Answer (score 1):

Override the `prepare(for: segue)` function in your ViewController (a), and present it from there:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "aToBSegue" {
        //present the popup view controller here.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    <#code for popup#>
}
```

Comment: I would suggest you write something more than just the code. Please explain how this piece of code works with a couple or a few sentences, as you see fit. It helps the person who asked the question to understand your thought process. Thank you very much!